# Advanced/Professional online data analysis courses

Tags: self-study, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I've been looking for some statistics, data analysis or other connected with bioinformatics field online courses. Unfortunately, many of them have an introduction or beginner level (like on coursera) and cover topic briefly.

I have bachelor degree in Applied Math and now i'm getting master's degree.

I do want to get my hands dirty with bioinformatics and applied math and ask you for some really good, advanced courses in these fields with hard practical part preferable.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This question is very broad. Would be answered best on Quora.

Answer (score 0):

If these data analysis courses seem simple, you could (if you don't already) start participating in contests like Kaggle or search for open data that you are interested in. The forums in these cases usually provide some basic guidelines to get you warmed up and you will have the chance to apply your expertise.

Comment: i know about Kaggle issues, but i don't feel ready to participate in that and actually it's not exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you for answer.